# Is it possible to create an IAM Policy that allows the the creation of only limited IAM Permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

As part of the process for onboarding new customers, I need to create an S3 bucket, create a new user, and grant that user permissions to get, list, and put to that bucket. I'd like to automate this process, which means that I need to create a "Provisioning" policy that grants a service only the permissions needed to do these things.

It seems pretty straightforward to use [String Conditions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Condition) in my Provisioning Policy to require the names of Users and Buckets start with a certain prefix. However, the [PutUserPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_PutUserPolicy.html) seems to just take a text blob as its argument. I'd prefer to limit my Provisioning Policy to only be able to create Policies that grant the specific permissions that I need here; ideally only being able to grant users who names match a pattern the ability to get, list, and put to buckets who names match a pattern. (If this Policy is somehow hijacked, I'd prefer to limit their ability to create a user and grant it *all* privileges.)

Is there any way to get this level of fine-grained control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. IAM doesn't go into this much detail. You can't say "Only allow a user to create a policy with these permissions".

You would need to design your system in such a way that this policy can't be hijacked. Create a template policy and just make sure a new user can't inject anything into the inputs.

Also, on a separate note, it would be considered much better practice to use one bucket and give each user a folder inside that bucket. You can still control permissions to a key in a bucket. See the [blog](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1P2T3LFXXCNB5/Writing-IAM-policies-Grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-Amazon-S3-bucke) for more on this.

Comment: I agree about buckets; however, I also need to create an SQS queue per-user, and then hand the user credentials to write to it, so I can't completely avoid creating a user. What do you mean "template policy"? Is this an official *thing* within AWS, or do you just mean creating the template programatically?

Comment: I never mentioned anything about avoiding creating a user, maybe you have misunderstood me? I mean creating the template programmatically.

Comment: I misspoke, I meant "avoid granting user permissions". I agree that creating polices from a template in this manner is safest; I am just nervous having a role with the "grant-any-permission" permission. If the server this runs on is *somehow* compromised (low likelihood), it could allow an attacker to quickly gain control of my AWS account (very high risk).

Comment: As I said in my answer it's not possible. You can either let the creation of policies be solely an admin thing, or create some API or interface that will prevent "anything" being added into the policy. You could have a separate user hooked up this API/interface and it would have the permission to create policies. But your customer's user wouldn't have this permission. They would have access to the API/interface - which if built securely would solve your problem. I don't think there are any other options.